# Integrate react app with php app

Tags: php, reactjs

I have an old php web application, with very bad code.
While a lot of it just has html and ajax calls in the, the wrapper is still php.

I want to develop the new modules in react, and slowly replace the old php modules one by one with react; Instead of doing everything from scratch.

What would be the best way to merge these?

Should I deploy the react modules else where, and embed using ajax calls with
`$("Div_ID").html()`?

Should I create each react module as a separate app and then do `include('index.html');` in php in each module's `index.php`

Can someone please just point me to a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do something good, you should separate the client and the server, php to manage all data access, and react to manage all the data received.

you took a look to vue.js? maybe it fit better with php and those things that you want make

Comment: Yes, thats the plan, but we dont have the time to get everything migrated to js first, and then start new modules. Need it to happen simultaneously / independently.